# How to invert sorting order in flatfile PHP?

Tags: php, sorting

I can't find the way to invert the order displaying the files fetched with this flat-file. What I want is the images with the higher numbers to be shown first. It's probably very easy but I can't figure it out.
Here the code:

```
<table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" width="760">

                <?php
                    $dir   = 'img/';
                    $filetype = '*.*';
                    $allow = array('jpg','jpeg', 'JPEG', 'JPG', 'gif', 'GIF', 'png', 'PNG');
                    $files = glob($dir.$filetype);
                    $i=0;
                    $open = opendir($dir);

                    while (($file=readdir($open))!==false) {
                    $ext=str_replace('.', '', strrchr($file, '.'));
                    if (in_array($ext, $allow)) 
                    $list[$i++]=$file; }

                    $perPage= 5;
                    $total=count($list);
                    $pages=ceil($total/$perPage);
                    $thisPage=isset($_GET['pg'])?$_GET['pg']-1:0;
                    $start=$thisPage*$perPage;
                    $pageNumber= $thisPage+1;
                    $perRow= 1;
                    $imgCnt=0; 
                    for ($i=$start;$i<$start+$perPage;$i++) {

                    echo "<div class='item' 'hyphenate'>";

                    if (isset($list[$i])) {

                        echo "<figure>";

                        echo '<div class="photo">';
                        // Image
                        echo '<img src="'.$files[$i].'" alt="">';

                        echo "</div>"; // Photo

                            echo "<figcaption>";                    

                                // Caption goes here

                            echo "</figcaption>";       

                        echo "</figure>";           

                    echo "</div>";

                    }else {
                    echo "<td></td>";
                    }

                    $imgCnt+=1; 
                    if ($imgCnt%$perRow==0)
                    echo "</tr><tr>";
                    }
                    echo "</tr>";

                    closedir($open);
                ?>
```

Comment: Are the filenames just numbers?

Comment: Numbers and names. The numbers are for sorting, the names are coming from the metadata and set the caption and alt text: "XX_YY_Image%title.jpg"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was making it too complicated in my head but the solution was as easy as adding `$files = array_reverse($files);` to my code, as you pointed out. Thanks!

Your solution for the img metadata formatting is good. I solved it like this:

```
        // Title    
        $title = substr($files[$i],strlen($dir),strpos($files[$i], '.')-strlen($dir)); // Fetch filename, ignore path and text since the '.'
        $title = str_replace( array( '%', '-'), " ", $title); // Replace symbols with a space
        $title = str_replace( array( '0', '1', '2' , '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '_'), "", $title); // Replace numbers and '_' with nothing
        echo '<h2>'."". $title .'</h2>'; // Show title

        echo '<p>'; 
        $exif = exif_read_data($files[$i], 0, true); // Get Exif metadata from image
        echo "" .$exif['IFD0']['ImageDescription']. "\n"; // Filter to IFD0 and ImageDescription
        echo '</p>';
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP function rsort (http://php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php) should do the trick. You could however create your own custom sorting using a callback function and the PHP function http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php (usort)

```
<?php
// function returns -1 if $a < $b, returns 1 if $a>$b and zero if equal
function mySortFunction($a, $b)
{
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    // next line should do the magic sorting. perhaps strip the numbers from the filename, convert to integer and then compare.
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}//mySortFunction

// call this function after your while loop 
usort($list, "mySortFunction");

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of [`natsort()`](http://php.net/natsort) and [`array_reverse()`](http://php.net/array_reverse).

From [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28428253/how-to-invert-sorting-order-in-flatfile-php?noredirect=1#comment45245741_28428253) it looks like we need to strip the separators (`_`) to make this work.

For example:

```
$files = glob($dir.$filetype);
$files = array_map('removeSeperators', $files); //Remove _ to make XXYY one number so we can sort.
natsort($files); //Sort naturally. (lowest-highest)
$files = array_reverse($files, true); //Reverse the array. (highest-lowest)

function removeSeperators($element) {
   return str_replace("_", "", $element);
}
```

https://eval.in/283459